# Qt::What needs to be included in the configuration to use dbus?

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, dbus

I'm using stripped down as much as possible configuration of Qt but now I need to use the dbus and can't figure out what I need to include to be able to use it? There doesnt seem to be anything obvious to me using the qconfig tool. The errors I get at the moment when making are:

```
qdbus_symbols.cpp:53: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
qdbus_symbols.cpp: In function ‘void qdbus_unloadLibDBus()’:
qdbus_symbols.cpp:57: error: ‘qdbus_libdbus’ was not declared in this scope
qdbus_symbols.cpp: In function ‘bool qdbus_loadLibDBus()’:
qdbus_symbols.cpp:67: error: ‘QLibrary’ was not declared in this scope
qdbus_symbols.cpp:67: error: ‘lib’ was not declared in this scope
qdbus_symbols.cpp:67: error: ‘qdbus_libdbus’ was not declared in this scope
qdbus_symbols.cpp:71: error: expected type-specifier before ‘QLibrary’
qdbus_symbols.cpp:71: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘QLibrary’
qdbus_symbols.cpp:85: error: type ‘<type error>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
qdbus_symbols.cpp: In function ‘void* qdbus_resolve_conditionally(const char*)’:
qdbus_symbols.cpp:93: error: ‘qdbus_libdbus’ was not declared in this scope
qdbus_symbols.cpp: In function ‘void* qdbus_resolve_me(const char*)’:
qdbus_symbols.cpp:103: error: ‘qdbus_libdbus’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [.obj/release-static-emb-x86/qdbus_symbols.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mark/qt-qvfb-4.5.3-static/src/dbus'
make: *** [sub-dbus-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Does anyone know a module that I must not be including which is necessary or how to find out? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QT += dbus
```

should be enough to include the dbus option in the .pro project file, ins't it?

I need more info to give apropriate answer.

Comment: QT += dbus will include it in the project file, but I'm talking about whats needed to be able to compile Qt with dbus included in the first place as I'm trying to make the install as small as possible.